# NewRelic - Java agent check that old package isn't used

Tags: java, package, newrelic, newrelic-platform

We introduce a new implementation which located in a different java package as `com.mycompany.myservice.newimpl`,

I want to validate old code (in old package as `com.mycompany.myservice.oldimpl`) isn't used,

Is there a way to view if java package as com.mycompany.myservice.oldimpl is been used or not?

[Custom instrument](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/manage-apm-agents/agent-data/custom-instrumentation) can be defined **only on specific method** in class and not on all package

> New Relic's Java agent supports two methods of custom instrumentation:
>
> Annotation: Add @Trace annotations to your code to ensure New Relic instruments specific methods.
>
> XML: Define the methods you want New Relic to monitor in an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can build a NRQL Query for this: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-data/nrql-new-relic-query-language/getting-started/introduction-nrql

Comment: I don't know how to exactly, but I know discuss.newrelic.com is active and can be helpful

Comment: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/check-if-java-package-being-used-using-nrql-query/87588

Comment: It seems there's no NRQL way from discuss *I don’t know that there’s any way in NRQL to get the info*